# (Ubuntu) Linux: Is it possible to find out if you're running inside §script§ command?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu, scripting

This arised when `~/.bashrc` kept creating `script` session on login unless quitted by CTRL+C, so I figured the particular command must have an `if` to check if we're already running a `script` session so it wouldn't create new ones indefinitely.

Comment: You can always walk your process tree to see who your parents are. What OS are you targeting? If you can assume Linux, then you can use procfs to make the job slightly easier.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Ubuntu (12.04.4).

Comment: ...well, wait -- if you're talking about indefinitely, that makes it sound like you're writing a tool that recursively calls itself under script. If *that's* the case, there are different, better ways to handle this.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I didn't believe it myself either, but having `script` in the `.bashrc` made it create sessions indefinitely cuz the file was run everytime a session was made and that's proved by not having to `exit` more than how many sessions it created; 5 extra sessions, recursively, inside the first.

I can't always have cronjob `chmod`ding `/dev/pts/` so I looked for ways and `script` seems to be the cure, but having to type it everytime you `su` ain't an option, but having `script` in `.bashrc` is really bad idea due to the recursive creating of `script` sessions.

Comment: What's your real goal? To log all of a user's actions? Running `script` as that user is absolutely the wrong way to do that; it's trivial for the user to evade or modify the logging, since a process they own necessarily has an open file handle on the log destination.

Comment: "Didn't believe it myself either"? It's completely believable, even **obvious**. `script` doesn't modify the existing shell session to be logged, it stats a new one as a child process. So, what do you think that child shell is going to start by doing?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I think I shoulda been more precise ... I mean to not have to use cron to make it possible to use `screen`. I need no logging, only to work around the complaint that not having correct permissions on the tty file cause. As long as I'm the only one with SSH and multiple users for different purposes this is workable, but it's annoying and still insecure.

Comment: ...*facepalm*. Next time, ask your _real_ question directly; this is the king of XY problems. (Fixing the underlying issue properly would be far better than deciding how to make a hacky workaround behave slightly better). (And who ever told you that the right fix involved `cron`?)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: The title is the question. I wouldn't use any hacky means to provide `screen` if `screen` worked its own problems by itself. I figured cron was a kind of a solution since the problem is called `missing permissions when using su via SSH`.

Comment: If the problem is missing permissions when using su via SSH, ask about that. Setting up your PAM modules to fix the TTY permissions when using su would be (an example of) a great solution to that problem. Having a setuid or passwordless-sudo-accessible script that fixes said permissions for the currently open TTY would be a good one. Using cron, by contrast, is a lousy solution -- high-latency, high-overhead.

Comment: ...you might also consider using `sudo -i` instead of `su`; sudo is far more TTY-aware.

Comment: See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: `sudo` is bad idea in the sense you run a single command instead of becoming that user until you `exit`, AFAIS.

Comment: That's not the only mode of operation sudo has, which is why I specifically suggested `sudo -i`.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: So `-i` makes `sudo` behave just like `su -` but is more knowledgeable about tty ?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to do something like

```
exec script "session.$(date)"
```

...in a case where recursion is possible, set an environment variable first, and proceed only when it isn't set:

```
[[ $- != *i* ]] && [[ -z $SCRIPT_RUNNING ]] && {
  export SCRIPT_RUNNING=1
  exec script "session.$(date)"
}
```

...the `$-` test skips this on noninteractive shells; the `SCRIPT_RUNNING` test skips it when previously set by a parent process.

That said -- if you're doing this for any kind of security purpose, it's entirely unsuited. Starting `script` from `.bashrc` means that the process that's logging a user's actions is owned and controlled by that user... conflict of interest, much? It also means that an interactive shell started with command-line arguments gets replaced by one without them, potentially breaking software doing interesting things.